# Filtering nested array of objects into two different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript object.Is there a way to filter the array in two different arrays , here the testData have division wise children , i want it to filter it into two different arrays one including data where the division wise children length is equal to 1 or the length of the children is 1 . i tried using filter function in es6

The test Array :

```
const testData = [
  {
    account: 'A',
    division_wise_children: [
      {
        account: '1',
        children: [
          {
            account: 'a',
          },
          {
            account: 'b',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    account: 'B',
    division_wise_children: [
      {
        account: '1',
        children: [
          {
            account: 'test',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    account: 'C',
    division_wise_children: [
      {
        account: '1',
        children: [
          {
            account: 'a',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        account: '2',
        children: [
          {
            account: 'a',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    account: 'D',
    division_wise_children: [
      {
        account: '1',
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];

// if division_wise_children length > 1 and the childern lenth is also > 1
const newArray1 = [
  {
    account: 'A',
    division_wise_children: [
      {
        account: '1',
        children: [
          {
            account: 'a',
          },
          {
            account: 'b',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    account: 'C',
    division_wise_children: [
      {
        account: '1',
        children: [
          {
            account: 'a',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        account: '2',
        children: [
          {
            account: 'a',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

// if division_wise_children length === 1 and the childern lenth is also 1
const newArray2 = [
  {
    account: 'B',
    division_wise_children: [
      {
        account: '1',
        children: [
          {
            account: 'test',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    account: 'D',
    division_wise_children: [
      {
        account: '1',
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: I think your `newArray1` and `newArray2` are not according to the conditions you mentioned. In `newArray1`, for account A, `division_wise_children` length is not > 1 and for account C, `children` length is not > 1. 

Similarly in `newArray2`, for account D, `children` length is 0.

Can you re-confirm your requirements by updating the question ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur i want to segregate the array of objects in 2 diffrent arrays , if the c.length is equal to one and the  length of the children's in  division_wise_children is equal to one .

Comment: @LakshyaThakur if you see in the first object the length of division wise children is equal to one but the length of the children is 2